# what is wrong with my findOutlier function? why am i getting error?

Tags: javascript

You are given an array (which will have a length of at least 3, but could be very large) containing integers. The array is either entirely comprised of odd integers or entirely comprised of even integers except for a single integer N. Write a method that takes the array as an argument and returns this "outlier" N

Example: [2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36]
Should return: 11 (the only odd number)

## my sol:

```
function findOutlier(integers){
var odd = false;
var even = false;
if ((integers[0]%2===0) && (integers[1]%2===0)) || ((integers[1]%2===0) && (integers[2]%2===0)){
    even = true;
}else{
    odd = true;
}

 if (odd){
    for (var i = 0; i < integers.length; i++){
        if (integers[i]%2 === 0){
            return integers[i];
    }}
}else if (even){
    for (var i = 0; i < integers.length; i++){
        if (integers[i]%2 !== 0){
            return integers[i];
 }}
}
}
```

Comment: Where is your `integers` `array`.

Comment: *"Why am I getting error"*. What error? there is none shown

Comment: You have too many `}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `if`-condition needs to be surrounded by parenthesis:
`if a || b` needs to be `if (a || b)`. Then it works. :)

```js
function findOutlier(integers) {
  var odd = false;
  var even = false;
  if (((integers[0] % 2 === 0) && (integers[1] % 2 === 0)) || ((integers[1] % 2 === 0) && (integers[2] % 2 === 0))) {
    even = true;
  } else {
    odd = true;
  }

  if (odd) {
    for (var i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
      if (integers[i] % 2 === 0) {
        return integers[i];
      }
    }
  } else if (even) {
    for (var i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
      if (integers[i] % 2 !== 0) {
        return integers[i];
      }
    }
  }
}

var result = findOutlier([2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36] );
console.log(result);
```

Here's another approach to solve that:

```js
function findOutlier(integers) {
  var outlier;
  var odd = [];
  var even = [];
  
  // Push odd numbers to odd array and even numbers to even array.
  integers.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element % 2 == 0) even.push(element);
    else odd.push(element);
  });

  // Ensure that the input is valid.
  if (odd.length != 1 && even.length != 1) {
    console.log("There is no single outlier! The array contains " + odd.length + " odd integers and " + even.length + " even integers.")
  } else {
    // Get outlier.
    outlier = (odd.length == 1 ? odd[0] : even[0]);
  }
  
  return outlier;
}

var result = findOutlier([2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36]);
console.log(result);
```